# How to find every comma and replace it with >

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

so i have a array

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
```

and i want the end result to be like this

```
var str="1>2>3>4>5>";
```

How do i do that?

I tried toString method and received this

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

but  i need to replace every comma with >
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use join. You can't replace the commas in an array-it's an array, not a string.

Comment: `arr.join('>')`

Comment: Can't you just use `.join('>')`?

Comment: Search a bit more before asking questions like this.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33376/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.join('>')); // prints "1>2>3>4>5"
```

If you want the trailing `>` you'll just want to append `>` to your string, like so: `arr.join('>') + ">"`

Answer (score 1):

Concat an empty string to the array, and then `join('>')` it:

```js
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5];

var result = arr.concat(['']).join('>');

console.log(result);
```